# libgdx collision/picking

Tags: java, libgdx, picking

I am trying to make something with java libgdx (2D). One thing that I can't figure it out is how to check mouse intersection with (fore example) isometric textures that are not rectangle shaped images. I found something about pickingColorPicking algorithm in libgdx, but I can't find any docs about how to use it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pixmap.getPixel(x,y)` method to find the color value at a certain pixel. To do collision checking, you could check the alpha value of that pixel. If it isn't zero, there is a collision.

Example:

```
public static int pixelAtPoint(float x, float y, Pixmap pix) {
    int pixel = pix.getPixel(x,y);
    return pixel;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely try this one. At least now it makes sense, I used similar technique in XNA framework.

Comment: Can you explain me one more thing. If I am drawing few textures (in different positions) at the same moment and I want to check if mouse point intersects one of them - how should I check that? Because with pixelAtPoint I'm only checking position in specific texture point, not in the point of the screen, right?

Sorry it's hard to understand what I'm asking.

Comment: if the texture is being drawn at point (100,100) on the screen, you can do something like pix.getPixel(x - 100,y-100);

Comment: You're amazing, man! It works. I just needed to add this:
if ((pixel & 0x000000ff) != 0) {
      // pixels collided
   }

so that game would compare transparent .png and now it works fine. Cool! Many, many thanks to You. :)